# Error while i am trying to deploy the function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy my code but I am getting error

My index code is:

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = 
functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{receiver_user_id}/{notification_id}')
.onWrite((data, context) =>
{
const receiver_user_id = context.params.receiver_user_id;
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

console.log('We have a notification to send to :' , receiver_user_id);

if (!data.after.val())
{
    console.log('A notification has been deleted :' , notification_id);
    return null;
}

const DeviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${receiver_user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

return DeviceToken.then(result =>
{
    const token_id = result.val();

    const payload =
    {
        notification:
        {
            title: "New Chat Request",
            body: `you have a new Chat Request, Please Check.`,
            icon: "default"
        }
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload)
    .then(response =>
        {
            console.log('This was a notification feature.');
        });
});
});
```

Error shown is this:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE  npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-02T11_48_47_185Z-debug.log
events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
}

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1


The error shown in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-02T11_48_47_185Z-debug.log :



 error code ELIFECYCLE

 error errno 1

 error functions@ lint: `eslint .`

 error Exit status 1

 error Failed at the functions@ lint script.

 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: How is your Android application interfacing with your javascript code?

Comment: Did you check `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-02T11_48_47_185Z-debug.log` as the error suggests? What's in it?

Comment: It's a linting issue right, check your lint script. If your code is in a folder like `src` change your script to `eslint src/*.js`. Even if it's in the root, .eslintignore the node_modules and make it `eslint *.js`

Comment: Please tell me how can I change it. I am not getting it

Comment: Do you have installed the eslint package correctly? Or maybe you have deleted it by mistake. Please recheck it, otherwise please put .catch to handle your error as @Mr Robot mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need the catch the error here:

```js
then(response =>
        {
            console.log('This was a notification feature.');
        }).catch(error => handle error here)
```